# Time picker validation OntimeSet android

Tags: android, validation, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

I am developing an application that requires a user to select From To time options but the problem I couldn't validate these two time like I want to avoid if the first time greater than the second time

```
@Override
    public void onTimeSet(int id, TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        String AM_PM = " AM";
        String mm_precede = "";
        if (hourOfDay >= 12) {
            AM_PM = " PM";
            if (hourOfDay >=13 && hourOfDay < 24) {
                hourOfDay -= 12;
            }
            else {
                hourOfDay = 12;
            }
        } else if (hourOfDay == 0) {
            hourOfDay = 12;
        }
        if (minute < 10) {
            mm_precede = "0";
        }

        //Check the started and ended of the an appointment
        sTimeApp.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + mm_precede + minute + AM_PM);
        eTimeApp.setText(hourOfDay + ":" +  mm_precede + minute + AM_PM);
        if (sTimeApp.equals(eTimeApp)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error , Time should be different ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }else {
            if (id == 3) {
                if (minute <= 9) {
                    sTimeApp.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + mm_precede + minute + AM_PM);
                }
            } else if (id == 4) {
                if (minute <= 9) {
                    eTimeApp.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + mm_precede + minute + AM_PM);
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Joda Time - it's much easier to use. Just include this in your gradle.build for the project:
        compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'

Then to make sure the time is greater you can do something such as(wrap both dates into their individual datetime):

```
//Note the +1 is required if using a calendar instance to get the month(it's 0-11, opposed to standard 1-12). If not, just remove.
DateTime startTime= new DateTime();
startTime.year().setCopy(theYear).monthOfYear().setCopy(theMonth + 1).dayOfMonth().setCopy(theDay).hourOfDay().setCopy(theHour).minuteOfHour(theMinute);
```

Then do something like:

```
if(startTime.getMilis() > endTime.getMillis())
```